Disjoint union of Cantor sets
Is Cantor set is homeomorphic to the disjoint union(in a categorical sense) of two its copies?
$C = \underset{\mathbb{N}}{\prod}\{ 0, 1 \}$
$C \coprod C = \{0, 1\} \times C =\{0, 1\} \times \underset{\mathbb{N}}{\prod}\{ 0, 1 \} = \underset{\mathbb{N}}{\prod}\{ 0, 1 \} = C$, where $\{0, 1 \}$ considered with discrete topology. Am I right?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.

You are right. For any space $X$, the disjont union $X \coprod X$ can be identified with the product $\{0,1\} \times X$. Thus
$$C \coprod C = \{0,1\} \times C .$$
But trivially $\{0,1\} \times C \approx C$ via $h(t, (x_i)) = (t, x_1, x_2, \ldots)$.

Yes. The Cantor set is the terminal coalgebra for the endofunctor $X \mapsto X + X$ on $\mathbf{Top}$ (see here or here). By Lambek's theorem, the coalgebra map $C \to C + C$ is an isomorphism.

Did you read what the OP wants to know?

Yes; what makes you think otherwise, @KritikerderElche ?

The OP asked for checking his elementary proof. Your approach is on a level far above.

I tried to make something interesting out of an uninteresting question. I believe the categorical perspective can be enlightening to more people than just the OP.

The disjoint union of two Cantor sets is homeomorphic to the prior according to the following:

Theorem: The Cantor set is the only totally disconnected, perfect compact metric space (up to homeomorphism).

This is corollary 30.4 from Willard's General Topology. So, if you want to prove that the disjoint union of two copies of the Cantor set is again a Cantor set, you should prove that the properties of being perfect, compact, totally disconected and metric are preserved by finite topological sums.
This is not a terribly hard thing to do; it can be reduced to a bunch of routinary exercises that are not hard to carry out, and are great work if you are not too familiar with the techniques that are typically used when you want to prove that certain topological properties can be extended for finite sums.
